# FreeTextBox only populates after page refresh

Tags: asp.net, sql

Im using "FreeTextBox" for users to edit web content (ASP.NET VB)

I query the database on pageload and set:

```
FreeTextBoxFoo.text = dbFoo.GetValue(2).ToString()
```

This DOES return the correct string data if I write it to an asp:Literal for example.

However nothing shows in the text box, until I refresh the page (F5)
Now in running the application in Visual studio in debug, it works ok.

So where is this string data getting lost, or hung? is it being loaded into the textbox but not displayed until a postback??

ETA: I forgot to mention this is inside an ASP:AccordionPane
Added more...
It seems that if I put the textbox outside the accordion panel, then it populates ok, so might be something to do with the order of execution?

Comment: This should be posted in stackoverflow - more developers there may give you a "better" answer. Can you try Response.Write(dbFoo.GetValue(2).ToString())   to see if the faults on load or not. Also, would need to see the code for the OnLoad method.

Comment: thats fair - can it be migrated?

as I mentioned, the database IS returning the correct string, but its not showing. 
I have moved the textbox outside of the accordion pane, and it loads OK, so it must be an effect of the accordion pane not refreshing after the data is posted to the textbox.

Comment: Your original post is not complete (see last sentence). It seems like you've answered your own question

Comment: it was complete but the more then / less than brackets around asp:accordionpane where cutting it out from display in the question.
well no, I have not answered the question, i now need to figure out how to get the accordion to refresh.

Comment: @DarkcatStudios You can request that the question be migrated with the flag function. I'd already set a close/move vote, but it takes several people to make that happen.